# Deleting a file from the web on a share drive

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Kinda new at this...

I am using ASP.net MVC 1 and I am trying to upload a file to a shared drive and delete/move a previous version of the file that is already on that shared drive.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of broad, but the basic building blocks of this will be just like any other .NET Application.

Scott Hanselman has a great article on doing this with ASP.NET MVC.  Once you handle the validation of the file upload, you can save / move / delete / etc... with the file.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx

A more simplistic approach (though similar) can be found here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Implementing_HTTP_File_Up.aspx